# eclipse / TFS hangs on startup

Tags: linux, eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I'm having an issue with eclipse / TFS at startup. It has worked normally for about a day, but now It just hangs on startup. It simply asks me to login to the TFS server but I cannot type anything anywhere:
[image: eclipse / TFS hangs on startup]

I tried launching eclipse with options `-debug -console`, and this is the output:

```
Start VM: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 610003
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-debug
-console
-vm /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 Install location:
    file:/opt/eclipse/ Configuration file:
    file:/opt/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded Configuration location:
    file:/opt/eclipse/configuration/ Framework located:
    file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar Framework classpath:
    file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar Splash location:
    /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp Debug options:
    file:/home/hhachem/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/.options not found Time to load bundles: 8 Starting application: 2862 osgi>  (Eclipse:4259): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/hhachem/.config/ibus/bus is not hhachem! Application Started: 10607
```

This is happening on :

```
uname -a
Linux linux-sb4w 3.11.10-21-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 21 15:28:46 UTC 2014 (9a9565d) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work again by deleting `.snap` in

```
<workspace directory>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

I hope this helps anyone having a similar issue.